# Cant add nuget package to universal portable library

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, nuget, nuget-package

I tried to add several packages with the nuget package manager to my universal portable library, I always get the following error message:

> Adding 'Package X.X.X' to MyLibrary. 
>   Could not install package 'Package X.X.X'. 
>   You are trying to install this package into
>   a project that targets 'portable-win81+wpa81', but the package does
>   not contain any assembly references or content files that are
>   compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the
>   package author.

I do understand what this error message is trying to tell me.

**What I don't understand:**

I tried to add the same nuget package with the package manager to my **universal application**, this works and indicates that the library is compatible with universal apps.

In my **universal portable library** I added the reference to the nuget package dll manually, this works as well. So I can add a reference manually, but not with the package manager console.

Why can't I add the nuget package with nuget package manager to my **universal portable library**?

**Additional Information:**

The package that I tried it with is the `Nokia Imaging SDK`. The problem can easily be reproduced by:

1. Create universal app
2. Create class library (Portable for universal apps)
3. Add the package to universal app (this works)
4. Add the package to the library (doesn't work)

Comment: What target frameworks does the package contain?

Comment: @MattWard  how can i get that info from the nupkg?

Comment: The .nupkg is a zip file so you can rename it to .zip and open it. The frameworks are in the lib folder inside the .zip. Another way is to use the NuGet package explorer - https://npe.codeplex.com/

Comment: @MattWard thanks, I didn't know about the explorer yet. According to the tool it's .NET v3.5

Comment: If the NuGet package only targets .NET 3.5 then NuGet will not allow you to install it into a PCL project. The NuGet package will need to include PCLs to be able to install it into a PCL project. What is strange is that you should not be able to install it into a Universal application. A Universal app should target WindowsPhoneApp which is not compatible with .NET 3.5. However I do not have VS 2013 to confirm the Universal application compatibility.

Comment: There is nothing to stop you from directly referencing an assembly. I do not believe Visual Studio will stop you. You may get a warning on compilation - not sure. The problem will be when you try to run it on a Windows 8 Phone or on Windows 8 where the assembly may use a part of the .NET framework which is not supported on Windows 8.